# Can't figure out why Django ORM is giving me this error with prefetch_related()

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I have the following data models in my Django app:

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    company_url = models.URLField(max_length=2048, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'company_table'

class PricingPlan(models.Model):
    plan_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, related_name='pricing_plans', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'pricing_plan_table'


class Feature(models.Model):
    feature_name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    plans = models.ManyToManyField(PricingPlan, related_name='features', blank=True)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'feature_table'

class WebData(models.Model):
    company = models.OneToOneField(Company, related_name='web_data', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    version = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    ...
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'web_data_table'
```

Now, I want to query the DB like this:

```
queryset = queryset.select_related('web_data').prefetch_related('pricing_plans', 'pricing_plans__features')
```

But get this error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "feature_table_plans" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e"."feature_name" FROM "feature_table" INNER JOIN "feature_t...
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch
queryset = queryset.select_related('web_data').prefetch_related(Prefetch('pricing_plans', queryset=PricingPlan.objects.prefetch_related('features')))
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Comment: tried it, but still get the same error:

django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "feature_table_plans" does not exist
LINE 1: ...e"."feature_name" FROM "feature_table" INNER JOIN "feature_t...

Comment: probably something wrong with your migrations. Have you done makemigrations and migrate commands?